# como pasar valor por href con php con metodo get?

Tags: php

estoy pasando un valor usando href con php y metodo get pero creo mi sintaxis esta mal ya que no me reconoce en el url este es mi codigo

```
$dni=09309393;
   echo'
     <label id="msjgd">EL PACIENTE SE REGISTRO CORRECTAMENTE EN LA PRIMERA FASE</label><br>
      <a id="cclinico" href="tarjeta.php?dni=$dni">CLICK PARA REGISTRAR CONTROL CLINICO</a>
    ';
```

pero en el url me sale tarjeta.php?dni=$dni 
y deberia salir tarjeta.php?dni=09309393

gracias

Comment: OP, ¿ha encontrado la respuesta válida a su pregunta entre una de las tantas respuestas a esta pregunta?

Answer (score 4):

Es porque para concatenar dicha variable de `PHP`, invocando al método `echo` con `'` es **imperativo** que la unas con `.`

```
$dni=09309393;
   echo'
     <label id="msjgd">EL PACIENTE SE REGISTRO CORRECTAMENTE EN LA PRIMERA FASE</label><br>
      <a id="cclinico" href="tarjeta.php?dni=' . $dni . '">CLICK PARA REGISTRAR CONTROL CLINICO</a>
    ';
```

Puedes referenciar directamente dicha variable solo si utilizas `"` en vez de `'`.

Answer (score 0):

si necesitas que tu dni tenga ese 0 del principio tienes que usarlo como String

```
$dni="09309393";
```

Ahora bien puedes  concatenar con el `.` pero es mas sencillo cambiar el tipo de comillas que usas, con las comillas dobles PHP detectara las variables dentro de tu string:

```
echo"
 <label id='msjgd'>EL PACIENTE SE REGISTRO CORRECTAMENTE EN LA PRIMERA FASE</label><br>
  <a id='cclinico' href='tarjeta.php?dni=$dni'>CLICK PARA REGISTRAR CONTROL CLINICO</a>
";
```

Answer (score 0):

prueba haciendo lo mismo pero en lugar de **'** utiliza **"**, otra opción es que en el momento mostrar tu variable hagas esto:

```html
$dni=09309393;
   echo'
     <label id="msjgd">EL PACIENTE SE REGISTRO CORRECTAMENTE EN LA PRIMERA FASE</label><br>
      <a id="cclinico" href="tarjeta.php?dni='.$dni.'">CLICK PARA REGISTRAR CONTROL CLINICO</a>
    ';
```

Answer (score 0):

Es extraño, pero normalmente la gente se pelea con los ' y los " del encadenado. Mi solución suele ser la siguiente:

```
$dni=09309393;
$result = sprintf('
  <label id="msjgd">EL PACIENTE SE REGISTRO CORRECTAMENTE EN LA PRIMERA FASE</label><br>
  <a id="cclinico" href="tarjeta.php?dni=%s">CLICK PARA REGISTRAR CONTROL CLINICO</a>',
  $dni); 

echo $result;
```

es decir, utilizar la funcion sprintf() en la que le indicas la cadena patron, y las variables con el % correspondiente.

Esto como ejemplo, siempre se pueden simplificar y quitar variables...